# ¿ Bug o Error de sintaxys en lenguaje batch?

Tags: windows, batch, powershell

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, y mi preparatoria estoy haciendo mi primer programa por lotes en batch, el problema es que trato de ejecutar el código pero aparece  "hay demasiados argumentos en la linea de comandos". A que se debe ?. Aquí están las imágenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]r.com/CaCUB.png

---

[image]

Esta es una captura despues de ejecutar el archivo .bat

Comment: Por favor no uses imágenes, en su lugar coloca todo el código como texto

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En lugar de capturas de pantalla, pulsa en [edit] y copia y pega el código de tu fichero en tu pregunta.